# 302 redirect when updating the cart via Ajax using Craft Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

I'm working on a site that has recently migrated from Craft v2 with Commerce v1 to Craft v3 with Commerce v2.

Using Commerce v1 I was able to update the cart via Ajax and get a data object with the state of the cart as a response.

After updating to Craft Commerce v2 the ajax requests fail, returning `Status 302 - Redirect` instead of the data object, although the changes to the cart are successful.

I can add one or more products or change their quantity via Ajax, however, I need the data object in order to properly update the state of the cart without reloading the page.

- I'm running Craft `v3.0.10.2` with Craft Commerce from `dev-develop` commit `1db58f6` on a machine running PHP `v7.1.12`
- The action I'm using is `commerce/cart/update-cart`
- The method of all requests is `POST`
- Any form data should to be ok since the cart updates succesfully
- All requests are sent with the following headers:

  `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
  X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

I'm I missing anything new in CC2? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function contains this

```
if ($request->getAcceptsJson()) {
```

Thus you'll need to set the `dataType` in your ajax request to `json` or `text/json` in order to not get redirected. If you didn't set it correctly Craft will treat it as a normal post request instead of an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. I had no idea CC2 was doing such a check.

Comment: Nearly all Craft 3 controllers have this condition. So should keep it in mind